show that: $\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1}+ \frac{2b^2+1}{b^4+6b^3+b^ 2+1}+ \frac{2c^2+1}{c^4+6c^3+c^2+1} \geq 1$
The problem
If $a>0, b>0$ and $c>0$ are real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, then show that the following inequality holds:
$\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1}+ \frac{2b^2+1}{b^4+6b^3+b^ 2+1}+ \frac{2c^2+1}{c^4+6c^3+c^2+1} \geq 1$
my idea
From $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ we can say that $\frac {a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}=1$ and we can replace it in the original inequality we have to demonstrate
$\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1}+ \frac{2b^2+1}{b^4+6b^3+b^ 2+1}+ \frac{2c^2+1}{c^4+6c^3+c^2+1} \geq \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}$
If we could show that $\frac{2x^2+1}{x^4+6x^3+x^2+1}=\frac{x^2}{3}$ everything would be solved
I tried doing so but got to nothing useful other than a bunch of numbers that are added or decreased
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

I think you can use the tangent line trick here.

@V.S.e.H. I dont know about this trick... i saw that implies functions, but I don't really know how to work with those. Is there any way to show without using them? Thank you for your idea, tho!

Are you familiar with derivatives? If yes, just try to find the tangent line where equality occurs. BTW there are many resources online on how the tangent line trick works.

@V.S.e.H.  You can not, doesn't work

It's like you're trying to minimize a scalar valued function $f(a,b,c)=\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1}+ \frac{2b^2+1}{b^4+6b^3+b^ 2+1}+ \frac{2c^2+1}{c^4+6c^3+c^2+1}$ given the constraint that $g(a,b,c)=a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. This sounds a lot like Lagrange multipliers...

Here's another way: note using AM-GM, $a^4+a^2\geqslant 2a^3$.  Using this, we may write:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1} \geqslant \sum_{cyc}\frac{2a^2+1}{4a^4+4a^2+1} =\sum_{cyc}\frac1{2a^2+1}\geqslant 1 $$
where the last inequality uses CS or Jensen.

CS in Engel form, yes, but Jensen not, because $f(t) = \frac{1}{2t^2  +1}$ is not convex (unless you had something else in mind). +1 for the AM-GM use though.

@V.S.e.H. But $1/(2x+1)$ is convex on $[0.\infty)$, which is where $a^2, b^2, c^2$ all live.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1} - 1\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1} - 1 + \frac29(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 3)\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\left(\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1} - \frac59 + \frac29 a^2\right)\\
 ={}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{ \left( 2\,{a}^{4}+16\,{a}^{3}+27\,{a}^{2}+8\,a+4 \right)  \left( a-1
  \right) ^{2}
 }{9\,{a}^{4}+54\,{a}^{3}+9\,{a}^{2}+9}\\
    \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}

Thank you so much for your answer! May I ask why $$ \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{ \left( 2,{a}^{4}+16,{a}^{3}+27,{a}^{2}+8,a+4 \right)  \left( a-1 \right) ^{2} }{9,{a}^{4}+54,{a}^{3}+9,{a}^{2}+9} \geq 0.$$

Isn't the $5/9$ supposed to be $5/3$?

Ah yes, forgot the cyclic summation.

@RiverLi Yes this is what i mean

@IONELABUCIU First, we want to find $s$ such that $\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1} - \frac13 + s(a^2 - 1) \ge 0$. Note that $\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1} - \frac13 = - \frac{(a - 1)(a^3 + 7a^2+ 2a + 2)}{3a^4 + 18a^3 + 3a^2 + 3}$. We have $$\frac{2a^2+1}{a^4+6a^3+a^2+1} - \frac13 + s(a^2 - 1)  = (a - 1)\left(- \frac{a^3 + 7a^2+ 2a + 2}{3a^4 + 18a^3 + 3a^2 + 3}  + s(a + 1)\right).$$ Then, $- \frac{a^3 + 7a^2+ 2a + 2}{3a^4 + 18a^3 + 3a^2 + 3}  + s(a + 1)$ must have a factor $a-1$. This is not a good solution if you do it by hand.

@IONELABUCIU   This is, in a sense, the tangent line trick that Vseh mentioned, but modified for our condition. Typically,  the tangent line trick is applied with the constraint $a+b+c = k$, where we let $f(a) - f(k/3) + s(a-k/3) = t(a) (a-k/3)^2  \geq 0$, so we can sum up the LHS to get $ f(a) + f(b) + f(c) \geq 3 f(k/3)$. In this case, because of the condition, we let $f(a) - f(1) + s(a^2 - 1) = t(a) ( a-1)^2$. $\quad$ (It is very reasonable to do this by hand lol.)

@CalvinLin Thanks. Yes, I do it by computer. It is not nice by hand.

I don't know if this can help you and if you're allowed to use graphs/analytical ways.
By drawing the graph of $f:=\frac{2x^2+1}{x^4+6x^3+x^2+1}$ and $g:=\frac{x^2}{3}$, you get $f\geq g\iff x\leq1$ (it would be $0<x^2\leq1$, but $x$ is always $>0$ because $a,b,c>0$). So you get that $a\leq1 \wedge b\leq1 \wedge c\leq1$, but you also have the condition that $\frac{a+b+c}{3}=1$. That is only obtained if you have $a=b=c=1$.
I don't know if there are other ways to solve this, I think it could be possible but I don't know which way to follow. Hope this can help you.
